# Spark: Access custom method with relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-spark

I've just bought Spark and I am a total Laravel-newbie, so bear over with me.

I'm trying to make a todo-app, how original :), just to get the hang of it, but I have a hard time getting the Eloquent relationship into Vue.
It works in `php artisan tinker`  where I can get the tasks for a Team with `App\Team::first()->tasks()->get()` which returns the associated tasks.

I can't figure out how to render them out, in Blade nor in the home/dashboard via Vue. 
How can I do this?